# Read digital signature authors/content

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, digital-signature, signature

I have a situation where a PDF contract file is generated and signed, then sent to a client, signed again, and returned.

On the last step I need to validate the 2 signatures, get the names of the people who signed it and display them as text.

Any recommendations on how to achieve this?

I found plenty of info on how to programmatically add a signature to a PDF file using .NET, but had no luck with reading the signature info on an already signed document.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [Spire.PDF](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html#.WnL7SqiWa70) that will do the work you need. I think you can try the free version without paying.

This page will lead you step by step on how to do it: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Get-and-Verify-Digital-Signature-in-PDF-with-C-Code.html